# How to validate & instantiate Java Locale from strings?

Tags: java, validation, locale

My app is being fed string from an external process, where each string is either 2- or 5-characters in length, and represents a `java.util.Locale`s. For example:

> en-us
>
> ko

The first example is a 5-char string where "en" is the ISO language code, and "us" is the ISO country code. This should correspond to the "en_US" Locale. The second example is only a 2-char string, where "ko" is the ISO language code, and should correspond to the "ko_KR" (Korean) Locale.

I need a way to take these strings (either the 2- or 5-char variety), validate it (as a supported Java **6** Locale), and then create a Locale instance with it.

I would have hoped that Locale came with such validation out of the box, but unfortunately this code runs without exceptions being thrown:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("waawaaweewah", "greatsuccess");

// Prints: "waawaaweewah"
System.out.println(loc.getDisplayLanguage());
```

So I ask, given me the 2 forms that these string will be given to me in, how can I:

- Validate the string (both forms) and throw an exception for strings corresponding to non-existent or unsupported Java 6 Locales; and
- Instantiate a new Locale from the string? This question really applies to the 2-char form, where I might only have "ko" and need it to map to the "ko_KR" Locale, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about you do a `new Locale(language)` for the second case and `new Locale(language, country)` for the first case assuming you split the input with a hyphen and treat the 2-char tokens as language and country?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Locale.getISOCountries()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getISOCountries%28%29) and [Locale.getISOLanguages()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getISOLanguages%28%29)

return a list of all 2-letter country and language codes defined in ISO 3166 and ISO 639 respectively and can be used to create Locales.

You can use this to validate your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options,

1. Use a library for doing this [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has the [LocaleUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/LocaleUtils.html) class that has a method that can parse a `String` to a `Locale`.
2. While your own method, the validation here is non trivial as there are a number of different sets of country codes that a valid for a `Locale` - see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

A starting point would be to split the `String` and switch on the number of elements:

```
public static Locale parseLocale(final String locale) {
    final String[] localeArr = locale.split("_");
    switch (localeArr.length) {
        case 1:
            return new Locale(localeArr[0]);
        case 2:
            return new Locale(localeArr[0], localeArr[1]);
        case 3:
            return new Locale(localeArr[0], localeArr[1], localeArr[2]);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid locale format;");
    }
}
```

Presumably you would need to get lists of all valid country codes and languages and compare the elements in the `String[]` to the valid values before calling the constructor.